# Read code from ESP12F / ESP8266

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, code, development

Is it possible to read the code that is programmed on an ESP12F/ESP8266? I don't even know which programming language is used.

This is a technical sheet for the ESP12F
http://wiki.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/a014ps01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

ESP8266 MCU doesn't has it's own flash memory for firmware/code/program/etc. Instead those modules, like ESP12F has an SPI flash chip on board, usually of 4Mb (32Mbit) size where it boots from and where all the program code & user data are stored.

So basically the answer for your question is - yes. You can always de-solder that SPI flash chip and read it without any issues as it can't be protected in any ways. So does there is no code readout protection for ESP8266 boards at all.

If you need a protection against code readout (device cloning) you have to pick other MCU or implement some sort of online crypto authorization (yes, that would require an Internet connection for that device).

ESP32 is another MCU from same company which offers code readout protection. But it was recently hacked and PoC exists on the Internet. It was fixed in most recent hardware revision so checkout for this: https://limitedresults.com/2019/11/pwn-the-esp32-forever-flash-encryption-and-sec-boot-keys-extraction/

Comment: So I need to de-solder the SPI flash chip to be able to read the program from the ESP12F?

Comment: @bjornsing I think you can simply use esptool (https://github.com/espressif/esptool) to just download program code from flash via MCU itself. Btw by mentioning programming language in your question I hope you understand that you get binary code by that, not the source on the high-level language.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can read the code, but what you can do is to read out the firmware version through the following AT command `AT+GMR` and then look it up online at the manufacturer's [website](https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/at).

Here is an example of the output of this command:

```
version:0.30.0.0(Jul 3 2015 19:35:49)
SDK version:1.2.0
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.
Build:1.2.0.A Aug 7 2015 17:21:44
OK
```

The list of commands supported by this chip can be found [here](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf).

Comment: Was there any reason for being down voted?

Comment: Because it's irrelevant to OP question and is wrong. AT-command firmware is only just the one possible of the codes which can be run on this MCU. And reading it doesn't have any sense as it's available on manufacturers website. The question was about reading a firmware which is easy as it can't be protected at all.

Comment: Sure, but as he mentioned he does not know what firmware is being used. If the MCU responds to the AT command (which is used in most off-the-shelf ESP8266 modules), it is good start.